# Can I give same name and id to an element in html text-field form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

My question is : Can I give same name and id to an element in html text-field form?

I can retrieve the values entered by user from the name identifier also, but as I have to use them in my functions in an external java script file, will giving both id and name identifiers be better and can both be given same identifier ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can give the same name and id to your form element. This is fine to have:

```
<input name="foo" id="foo" ... />
```

Comment: It is also valid to have multiple elements with the same name (even required to make radio buttons meaningful). It is not, however, valid to have multiple elements with the same ID.